# How to run a script as soon as the week number changes?

Tags: cron

I would like to keep my download folder sorted. My goal is to have the files of the current week in the download folder, and the older files in a folder named after week number and year (eg 2013.09, lexicographically sortable) of the creation date of these files.

I only want this to apply to the files and folders found at the root of download folder; `tar` archives and others archives are sometimes automatically expanded by the browser when the download is complete.

Files and folders currently at the root of the download folder are assumed to be the ones of the current week. However, mtime and ctime don't tell when the file actually finished downloading.

If the machine was always on, I could set a cron task to run as soon as the week number changes, but this is a laptop, and I put it in stand by mode when I don't use it.

Comment: Run the script every day, and check in the script if something is to do or not.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Set the crontab as:

```
@reboot the-script
0 0 * * 1 the-script
0 0 1 1 * the-script
```

To have it done on Mondays and at each boot. And in `the-script`, check if it's already been done. (if using the `%W` for the week number, you need also to do it on the first of January (thanks Gilles), not if using the ISO 8061 week number (%V)).

If your `cron` doesn't support `@reboot`, you'd have to add it to a startup script.

Or just run it daily and do something like (assuming `GNU` `find`, so not OS/X, though you could use OS/X `stat` in combination with `-exec ... {} +`.

```
 cd ~/Download || exit
 find . -path './20[0-9][0-9].[0-9]*' -prune -o -type f -mtime +7 -printf '%p\0%TY.%TW\0' |
   xargs -r0n2 sh -c 'mkdir -p "$2" && exec mv -i "$@"' sh
```

(untested)

Or with `zsh`:

```
zmodload zsh/stat
cd ~/Download || exit
for f (**/*~20[0-9][0-9].[0-9]*(.DNm+7)) {
  zstat -A d -F %Y.%W -- $f &&
    mkdir -p $d &&
    mv -i -- $f $d
}
```

If you don't want to do it recursively, it's simpler:

```
zmodload zsh/stat
cd ~/Download || exit
for f (*(.DNm+7)) {
  zstat -A d -F %Y.%W -- $f &&
    mkdir -p $d &&
    mv -i -- $f $d
}
```

If the last modification time doesn't reflect the time of download, then you may be able to use the birth time. This time using OS/X `find`, `stat` and `xargs` (and using `-maxdepth 1` to *not* recurse):

```
find . -type f -maxdepth 1 -Btime +7 \
  -exec stat -nf%SB -t%Y.%W {} \; \
  -exec printf '\0' \; \
  -print0  | xargs -0n2 sh -c '
  mkdir -p "$1" && mv -i "$2" "$1"' sh
```

Comment: Thanks. Does this solution work when the machine comes back from stand-by mode ? Because technically I rarely turn it off completely, I put it in stand by/hibernate mode.

Comment: @AntoineLecaille. The first one doesn't. `cron` runs the `@reboot` jobs when it starts. The second one, you could run hourly instead of dayly.

Comment: OS X has GNU find available through macports. However I have not checked how well it's working on the latest (Mavericks) version. It looks like it's not immediately available right now.

Comment: Does the zsh version recursively move every file, destroying the directory structures ? My download folder happens to contain expanded tar archives for example.

Comment: Another problem is that mtime seems unrelated to the date I downloaded the file.

Comment: May I ask you what the last `sh` is in the last script ?

Comment: @AntoineLecaille, that's to set `$0` within the inline script (which is used when reporting errors for instance).